# Restructure of Express CORS middleware for unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, express.js

How should one break this component down to better perform unit test on its behaviors?

**Issues:**

- Authentication middleware component makes external request.
- Must recognize preflight and final flight. (Exceptions)
- Must verify path.
- Only want to expose `crossOriginRequest`.

Please criticize anything you see wrong in logic and implementation!

**EDITED: 3-28-16 @ 3:40pm PST**

```
var httpErrors = require('./errors');
var authentication = require('./auth');

// CORS permission for paths.
var HEADERS = {
    "img": [
        "GET"
    ]
};

function _acceptsMethod(requestMethod, requestPath) {
    return HEADERS[requestPath].indexOf(requestMethod) >= 0;
};

function _getMethods(requestPath) {
    return HEADERS[requestPath].join();
};

function _getCorsRequest(req) {
    return {
        preflight: ("OPTIONS" == req.method),
        endpoint: (req.originalUrl.split('/')[2] || null)
    };
}

var crossOriginRequest = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['origin']) {
        req.cors = false;  
        var cors = _getCorsRequest(req);

        // Access-Control-Allow-Origin needs to be set in preflight and flight.
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers['origin']);
        if (cors.preflight && cors.endpoint) {
            if(!_acceptsMethod(req.headers["access-control-request-method"], cors.endpoint)){
                next(httpErrors.badRequest('Failed endpoint method requirments.'))
                return;
            }
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', _getMethods(cors.endpoint));
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
        }

        if (!cors.preflight) {
            var auth = req.authentication = authentication.getAuthParameters(req);
            authentication.check(auth.endpoint, auth.auth, auth.cors)
                .then(function(user) {
                    user = JSON.parse(user);
                    if (user.data.cors) {
                        req.cors = true;
                        next();
                    } else {
                        next(httpErrors.forbidden('Access denied with CORS.', {
                            error: user.data.cors
                        }));
                        return;
                    }
                }).catch(function deniedAuth(err) {
                    next(httpErrors.forbidden('Access denied.', err));
                    return;
                }).done();
        } else {
            // Send empty body as to not overwrite "OK".
            res.status(200).send('');
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

module.exports = crossOriginRequest;
```